# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression oracle how to group by?

Tags: oracle10g, group-by

I have an application that uses Hibernate.  It generated the following SQL statement.  I am trying to modify the query to group the data but I keep getting an error

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

The query

```
>  select
>         snstoken0_.id as id20_0_,
>         snstokenme1_.SNS_MESSAGE_ID as SNS2_21_1_,
>         snstokenme1_.SNS_TOKEN_ID as SNS3_21_1_,
>         snsmessage2_.id as id19_2_,
>         snsmaster3_.id as id17_3_,
>         snstokenpr4_.id as id22_4_,
>         snstoken0_.ACTIVE_STATE as ACTIVE2_20_0_,
>         snstoken0_.MEMBER_ID as MEMBER8_20_0_,
>         snstoken0_.SNS_MASTER_ID as SNS9_20_0_,
>         snstoken0_.TOKEN1 as TOKEN3_20_0_,
>         snstoken0_.TOKEN2 as TOKEN4_20_0_,
>         snstoken0_.TOKEN3 as TOKEN5_20_0_,
>         snstoken0_.DATE_TOKEN as DATE6_20_0_,
>         snstoken0_.USERNAME as USERNAME20_0_,
>         snstokenme1_.ARTICLE_ID as ARTICLE1_21_1_,
>         snstokenme1_.SNS_TOKEN_ID as SNS3_20_0__,
>         snstokenme1_.SNS_MESSAGE_ID as SNS2_0__,
>         snstokenme1_.SNS_TOKEN_ID as SNS3_0__,
>         snsmessage2_.ACTIVE_STATE as ACTIVE2_19_2_,
>         snsmessage2_.CONTENT_ID as CONTENT5_19_2_,
>         snsmessage2_.MESSAGE_TEXT as MESSAGE3_19_2_,
>         snsmessage2_.SNS_MESSAGE_ID as SNS6_19_2_,
>         snsmessage2_.POST_DATE as POST4_19_2_,
>         snsmaster3_.ACTIVE_STATE as ACTIVE2_17_3_,
>         snsmaster3_.ACTIVE_ICON as ACTIVE3_17_3_,
>         snsmaster3_.AUTHENTICATION_URL as AUTHENTI4_17_3_,
>         snsmaster3_.BREAK_TOKEN_URL as BREAK5_17_3_,
>         snsmaster3_.INACTIVE_ICON as INACTIVE6_17_3_,
>         snsmaster3_.NAME as NAME17_3_,
>         snsmaster3_.URL_WEBSITE as URL8_17_3_,
>         snstokenpr4_.ACTIVE_STATE as ACTIVE2_22_4_,
>         snstokenpr4_.SNS_TOKEN_ID as SNS5_22_4_,
>         snstokenpr4_.VALUE as VALUE22_4_,
>         snstokenpr4_.VAR as VAR22_4_,
>         snstokenpr4_.SNS_TOKEN_ID as SNS5_20_1__,
>         snstokenpr4_.id as id1__ 
>     from
>         SNS_TOKEN snstoken0_ 
>     left outer join
>         SNS_TOKEN_MESSAGE snstokenme1_ 
>             on snstoken0_.id=snstokenme1_.SNS_TOKEN_ID 
>     left outer join
>         SNS_MESSAGE snsmessage2_ 
>             on snstokenme1_.SNS_MESSAGE_ID=snsmessage2_.id 
>     left outer join
>         SNS_MASTER snsmaster3_ 
>             on snstoken0_.SNS_MASTER_ID=snsmaster3_.id 
>     left outer join
>         SNS_TOKEN_PROP snstokenpr4_ 
>             on snstoken0_.id=snstokenpr4_.SNS_TOKEN_ID 
>     group by
>         snstoken0_.MEMBER_ID
>     having
>         snstokenpr4_.VAR='PROFILE_IMAGE'
```

Comment: I do not see any aggregate function in your query. Perhaps you don't want to group by member_id but order results by this column.

Comment: Is this query generated by Hibernate or did you write it yourself? If it's Hibernate, what is the HQL that produced this query? If you wrote it yourself, like @Marcin Wroblewski said, it's not a group by SQL.

Comment: it was written by hibernate. not group by SQL??so it must have a agrregate function? ok...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give a GROUP BY clause in your query, it MUST include all non-aggregate expressions in the SELECT list (aside from a few exceptions for literals and some deterministic functions).

In your case, you need to repeat the entire expression list (following the SELECT) after the GROUP BY.

(If this is being produced by Hibernate, then Hibernate is producing SQL that is invalid for Oracle.)